# Sort Safari debugger network tab chronologically

Tags: debugging, safari

I'm using Safari to debug a web application. I would like the Network tab to show the activity as it occurs in chronological order but I can't figure out how to sort it that way. I'm pretty sure it used to be sorted that way by default but I can't figure out how to get it back. Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: Top two hits in Google are this and one that looks also like you in the [Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250022087), and yet neither have a single response. Can't believe no one knows how to do this, or that it's even an issue to begin with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, try clicking the header of the timeline column to sort chronologically. Clicking it again toggles between an ascending or descending sort.

[Safari Sort Chronologically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LAkr.png)

Comment: Thanks you! I also noticed there's a little caret on the far right hand side of that column you can use to toggle the sort direction.

Answer (score 10):

Show the [waterfall column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70J6g.png) and sort by it. It should order the requests by the time, when they started (when sorting in ascending order).